# Making an action.http from an Adaptive Card

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am trying to POST from an Active Card, but the http action does not seem to be supported.  I have researched and found a number of references to action.http, but, the schema only shows Submit, OpenURL, ShowCard.  Can anyone provide some guidance around this?

Comment: Here is an extract from Git post by Microsoft :

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards

Finally, Adaptive Cards support special elements that enable interaction:

Action.OpenUrl

Action.Submit

Action.Http

Action.Http represents the properties needed to do an Http request. All input properties are available for use via data binding. Properties can be data bound to the Uri and Body properties, allowing you to send a request to an arbitrary url.

Action.ShowCard

Comment: You have a broken link.  Can you fix it ?

Comment: Seems to have been removed in this merge https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/pull/651/commits/424fb24538af68c20998851669acb26c6ef2530c - Not sure how to pass a body in an Action.Submit